where is the background.js and content.js when using vite to build react project for web extension
I'm new to react and i use vite I want to create web extension with background and content script
the background.jsx is empty for now and here it is the content.jsx
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from "./App.jsx"

const root = document.createElement('div')
root.id = "react-root"

document.body.appendChild(root)

ReactDOM.createRoot(root).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
)


it just add root div to the host site and render the app component in it
( the App is component for pupop that need to be added to the current visible tab )
the problem is that i can't access the content.jsx in the manifest.json
if i put the content.jsx in /public after building it remains as .jsx and i can't use that in web extension
and if i put it in /src it adds it to the index.js with all the App codes so i can't use it either
my project is a miss because it's my first project with react & vite i know how to make web extensions but only with vanilla javascript so it might be ease problem to solve but the tutorials i watched only uses the index.html as popup or something else with no background.js or content.js

Hey, I'm facing the same problem, please let me know if you've found a solution for this. Thanks
